# menu in different page in different style

Tags: widgets, menus

I have a one column page for the home page where I have a mega menu and in side the site there is another page called about us  where the mega menu is present but it is in small format just like it differs from the mega menu in width and height.So for home page I have used widget and now for about us page I want the small mega menu.So can any one tell me how to do that.I heared about if(front_page()), so I am using this but nothing is happening.So please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you read:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: "So can any one tell me how to do that" - Do what? What was the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this,

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ):?>
<div class="home-page-menu">
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
</div>
<?php elseif; ?>
<div class="inside-page-menu">
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here, you should be change your CSS style for home-page-menu and inside-page-menu .
for more details about this `is_front_page()` follow this link 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page